# What is the efficient way to extract integer from a string wrap with symbolic character?

Tags: python, performance, split

The objective is to extract an integer from a string. To achieve this, the code below was realised.

```
my_string=' W\\x14\\x00+30630\\x15120\\x14'
interested_integer = my_string.split('\\')[2].split('+')[1]
print(interested_integer)
```

But, I am curious whether there exist much more efficient and compact approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
my_string=' W\\x14\\x00+30630\\x15120\\x14'
import re
print(re.split('\\\\|\+',my_string)[3])
```

Comment: Elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex:

```
import re

my_string=' W\\x14\\x00+30630\\x15120\\x14'

out = re.findall('\d+',my_string)
print(out)
out = [int(x) for x in out]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['14', '00', '30630', '15120', '14']
[14, 0, 30630, 15120, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want logic to look for the number after the `+`

```
print(re.findall(r'\+\d+', my_string)[0][1:])
```